# Searching for a word or phrase

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I am looking for a word or phrase to express the idea of making one thing into an entirely new, better thing.

To give a little bit of context, this is in reference to recycling and upcycling.

Comment: How about *recyling*? *Reshaping*?

Comment: Transformation?

Comment: You can start your search by looking up a word such as "change" and then search for synonyms.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Repurposing would certainly apply to the context of recycling.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [***revamp***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/revamp) is an appropriate term here. Although not associated with recycling per se it really captures the improvement bit.

> Give new and improved form, structure, or appearance to:
> *an attempt to revamp the museum’s image*
> (as adjective **revamped**) *a revamped magazine*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/revamp

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [*transmogrify*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transmogrify):

> **transmogrify** ‎(third-person singular simple present **transmogrifies**, present participle **transmogrifying**, simple past and past participle **transmogrified**)
>
> 1. (transitive) To completely alter the form of.
> 2. (intransitive) To completely alter one's form.

This word was used by Bill Watterson in his comics *Calvin and Hobbes* as a name for an imaginary invention which can completely alter one thing into another: [*the transmogrifier*](http://calvinandhobbes.wikia.com/wiki/Transmogrifier).

Comment: There is no requirement of 'a better thing' here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that's fair; it was merely an alternative idea for OP's use if they wanted it. My original suggestion would've been "revamp", but that had already been submitted. :)

Comment: Alternative ideas should be confined to 'comments' unless directly requested. OP here requests the 'better' constraint.